# Fancy site style has vanished (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markup

I'm viewing the site on my mobile right now and it doesn't have any of the custom styling. It's all gray with generic fonts. I was on my desktop an hour ago and it looked fine. Is there a stylesheet that's gone missing or is this by design?

Here is a screenshot.

[image: screenshot of mobile site with no styling]

**Update** I'm back at a desktop and it looks fine.  I think it's really a mobile issue because when I used Safari on the Mac and changed the user agent to iPhone there again was no style.

**Resolution** Hendrik points me in the right direction below.  It's not a bug; it's a feature.  Mods, if you could tag this status-bydesign that would be best.

Comment: For me, the meta stylesheet didn't work on Firefox some days ago (it did on IE). Over at math.sx, [other people seem to have the same issues](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726/again-with-the-style-change).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug, [it's a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-iphone-optimized-version-of-so/50689#50689). In general it's always good to have a look here: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I was just surprised since I saw the regular style on my mobile yesterday and today it was gone.  And for my money I'll call it a "feature" when the layout (not just the style) is more mobile-friendly.

Comment: I'd say 'a good thing': access on my phone has to date been painful

Answer (score 2):

Correct, we are starting with some basic designs to test mobile rendering.

The /minimal style is the "hello world" of mobile designs, it is the absolute minimal CSS and images necessary to render the site.

We will be improving this over the next few months.